# Type error when using stripe with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, stripe-payments, react-typescript

Unable to use the type declaration with `onChange` event, while working with Stripe's `<LinkAuthenticationElement/>` with React.

I am using `@stripe/react-stripe-js` package.

Here is my code:-

```js
<LinkAuthenticationElement
    id="link-authentication-element"
    onChange={(event:React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => setEmail((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value)}
/>
```

And it giving error on the `onChange`:-

```js
Type '(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: StripeLinkAuthenticationElementChangeEvent) => any'.
  Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'StripeLinkAuthenticationElementChangeEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>': altKey, button, buttons, clientX, and 29 more.ts(2322)
react-stripe.d.ts(278, 5): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LinkAuthenticationElementProps'
```

I tried updating the type `React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>` to `StripeLinkAuthenticationElementChangeEvent` but was unable to access `event.target.value`.

I am very new to TypeScript, please help me figure out a way.

Comment: Have you tried checking the value of event ?

Comment: @geeky01adarsh., could you provide the exact package name of the stripe?

Comment: @FlorentM. its's an email field for the validation purpose

Comment: @Gavara.Suneel I am using @stripe/react-stripe-js

Comment: You should be able to get the value with `event.value` without target: https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/events?type=linkAuthenticationElement

Comment: In those cases the firsts things to check are the type documentation of the object and its actual value

Comment: @FlorentM. thanks for the advice, I tried of understanding the documentation but was stuck. Will take care of it from next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the value from the `event.value` by providing the type `StripeLinkAuthenticationElementChangeEvent` to it.

```js
<LinkAuthenticationElement
    id="link-authentication-element"
    onChange={(event:Stripe.StripeLinkAuthenticationElementChangeEvent) => setEmail(event.value)}
/>
```

Make sure your email(setState hook) is of type `{email:string}`